# Database for realtime web application (Low latency response)

Tags: php, mysql

The application is real time site that need a speed of query (select, update, insert) Low latency must less than 200ms every query

Well, On average 98% each query. time is less than 0.001-0.005 secound on for complete job query.

the problem is
sometime around 5 time per hour, they can take up to 1s and may be 5s, i don't know real cause of problem

i found to reducing the problem are move that from INNODB to MEMORY but sometime still a problem and the important thing are need recovery when system has crash.

```
Example query in sometime query more than 1 secound

# Time: 130328 20:27:40
# User@Host: ferge572w[ferge572w] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 1.339712  Lock_time: 0.000026 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1364477260;
UPDATE log_product SET credit=credit+1 WHERE id_product='149721921' and id_user='2029275' LIMIT 1;

table index: id_product, id_user
No.row: 33,491   table size: 5Mb

# Time: 130329  7:25:37
# User@Host: ferge572w[ferge572w] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 1.439856  Lock_time: 0.000031 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1364516737;
UPDATE product SET lastuser='hello',picperson='1',lastid='2030505',country='thailand',price=price+0.01,time=DATE_ADD(time, INTERVAL 3 SECOND) WHERE id='349721227' LIMIT 1;

table index: id
No.row: 35   table size: 2.1Mb
```

My application use PHP and MYSQL

**The question are why sometime the query can take time up to 5 second ?**

Comment: What makes absolutely no sense is this post of yours. And what is the question?

Comment: Your question as it stands is too broad. You need to pick a single problem and ask for help on how you can better optimize your solution.

Comment: You should start by enabling/examining the slow query log

Comment: My table are MEMORY engine, i don't know why sometime the query can take time up to 5 secound. for example update see above. thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've given very little in the way of details. I'll provide an answer here that's as simple as possible:

## **Use SSD**

If you're not already using SSD that's probably the issue. Conventional hard drives are terrible at random I/O and will bog down on occasion when too busy to service requests in a timely manner. MySQL seems to fly into an absolute panic when out of I/O cycles and performance falls off a cliff.

Comment: My table are MEMORY engine, i don't know why sometime the query can take time up to 5 secound. for example update see above. thank

Comment: Using `MEMORY` in production is like juggling chainsaws. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: Ok so what should i do because i need low latency SELECT and UPDATE

Comment: InnoDB, throw lots of memory at `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, and index on only those columns required to get to your data quickly. You'll need to monitor the various InnoDB diagnostic variables to see what's going on, but that's just from any "How to Tune InnoDB" handbook. `SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS` can be used to diagnose what's causing locks.

Comment: SHOW ENGINE innodb STATUS, what factor to effect latency. i ensure innodb_buffer_pool_size > all size of innodb table. no deadlock. now i use MEMORY engine but still some slow.